# Pagination vs Scroll in Datagrid

Tags: grid, pagination

Normally, we can use pagination and scroll in a datagrid when it has too many records.

How to balance when to use pagination or scroll, **considering consistency in standard guideline in a whole system**?

The pattern will be applied in a lot of functions in the system. Thus, there are multiple types of grid in used:

Basic Datagrid

[image]

Groping in datagrid

[image]

Treegrid

[image]

Row Expander Grid

[image]

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE! What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually, in my application, it has above various patterns grid in used. while we need a standard to guide mates how to use pagination and scroll when design new UI. The standard guideline shoud be easy reference for mates to follow and keep consistency.

Comment: I am having trouble imaging how you would even implement paging in a treeview?  I have never seen a paging treeview.   To me a paging treeview would be clunky at best.   To me scroll wins UX every time.  I just do paging when there is just plain too much data for the UI to handle with good response time.

Answer (score 1):

The three major considerations that will have to be weighed up for your project are:

1. **Complexity of information** - datagrids are suitable for information that has more or less a linear nature or hierarchy, or at least nothing to deep. So when you apply the rule in the style guide you probably shouldn't be applying only scrolling or pagination because it won't necessarily be suitable for everything. In the end, if the user cannot view the content easily then you should consider different ways to display the information.
2. **Performance** - this seems to be an important factor, but is also related to the complexity of the underlying information or data. Having to load all the data when there can be a considerable list means that the performance takes a large hit when the user may just want to perform a simple task. This also depends on the ability to easily search, sort, filter or navigate the table. In the end, if it takes too long to load the data then you should consider different ways to retrieve and display the information.
3. **Impact** - if the datagrid is used in many different places, and for a number of task that are commonly carried out, then both 1 & 2 become very important to optimize. In the end, if the impact across the website is significant, then it is critical to address this design task as a high priority issue.

Answer (score 0):

Having one pattern across the whole experience is usually a great idea.  But don't force it.  You may have to rely on a pagination model where there is a technical limitation in a few cases; it would be a loss to limit the whole interface to suit a minority of instances.

**discoverability**

The key to either model is making it obvious to users that there is more to look at (and letting them see how).  Some paginated models make it hard to see and can lead to users making decisions on the top-n records not knowing about n+1 (particularly bad if the are accustomed to having less than a pageful and don't notice the second page become available).

**scroll your paged data - infinite scroll**

If you have paginated data in the API you can still scroll it by loading the next page(s) below/above before they are needed. *Tiled web map/Slippy map* interfaces use this for 2 dimensional scrolling across paged/tiles data. (You'll need to handle the *loading* case for fast scrollers of course.)

Answer (score 0):

Either to go with Pagination or Infinite scroll is based on what requirement demands.

Pagination - Assuming for the above requirement i recommend for the pagination option. If the data is huge, this is the best option to drive. Its good in terms of scalability.

Infinite scroll - This option is used widely on the e-commerce site, this is best suit for the e-commerce website. The problem with this is i can't jump to 5th or 10 page. Visually this options is better with tiled or list view of the data.